# is it possible to maintain variable after exiting program (background entering)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label which user will set the number after that user hits the button the number will be stored in numbers variable.in **appdelegate.m** I want to **access** the number which has been set.
for example the input that label has is **9:25**
here is what I have done.I think that it is wrong to declare my viewcontroller in appdelegate.m but I didn't know what to do else.

ShowOfNotificationViewController.h

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *numbers;
```

ShowOfNotificationViewController.m

```
@implementation ShowOfNotificationViewController
@synthesize numbers;

- (IBAction)setTime:(id)sender {
numbers=TimeLabel.text;
}
```

ShowOfNotificationAppDelegate.m

```
#import "ShowOfNotificationAppDelegate.h"
#import "ShowOfNotificationViewController.h"

    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        ShowOfNotificationViewController *m;

         NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        NSArray *listItems = [m.numbers componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        NSNumber * myNumber1 = [f numberFromString:listItems[0]];
        NSNumber * myNumber2 = [f numberFromString:listItems[1]];
        NSLog(@"%@",myNumber1);
        NSLog(@"%@",myNumber2);
    }
```

the output is null,null

Comment: <Insert answer about NSUserDefaults below>

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Show me the initialization of that NSNumberFormatter f

Comment: @CodaFi here is the f variable

Comment: They are null because the m instant is not the same as the other instant of the ShowOfNotificationViewController class that you have hit the buuton with.

Comment: @user523234 what instance?  All I see is a stub declaring that m is of type pointer to `ShowOfNotificationViewController`

Comment: @Codafi: Some how I read the line wrong... m and f..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!-- @CodaFi: here you are -->
```

**If it is not sensitive data,** you can store the value in the user defaults which is persisted to disk by the OS:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.numbers forKey:@"Numbers"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And to retrieve it:

```
self.numbers = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Numbers"];
```

Comment: I can't access numbers from self in appdelegate where this code should be inserted? is it placed on controller.m?

Comment: @nikparsa You decide that. Wherever it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Man, you should alloc init your ShowOfNotificationViewController and store it into a property or some class ShowOfNotificationViewController * var...

You can't hope that the simple ShowOfNotificationViewController *m; will allow your application to know that you want to get a specific element....

You are just defining a var, but you are not assigning it... what should the program do with that?

Try to think about that:
m should be a person, but he is not here! Where is he? who knows.
Of course when you say m, what is your name, nobody will answer you. (null)

but if you say m = giovanni;
and then you ask to m his name he will answer "giovanni"!

What you need to do is 
ShowOfNotificationViewController *m = some ShowOfNotificationViewController previously created;

this will work.

Comment: I'm not man.yes you're absolutely right but I didn't know how to set it and then use it

Comment: It's easy. In your appDelegate.h create a property, alloc, init it in your app did finishLunching and in your did enter foreground refer to it by using self.yourVar. this is a way.